# draw geometric vector diagrams for given df and generate .png

Tags: r, animation, vector, rgl

Using `matlib` package I'was able to to draw geometric vector diagrams. 
using following code one can draw 3d vectors for given coordinate

```
library(matlib)
library(rgl)    
vec <- rbind(diag(3), c(1,1,1))
rownames(vec) <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "J")
open3d()
vectors3d(vec, col=c(rep("black",3), "red"), lwd=2)
```

[image]

However, when I want to supply a coordinates from a `df`

```
set.seed(12)
x <- runif(10,-0.14,0.1)
y <- runif(10,-0.14,0.1)
z <-sort(runif(10,-0.9,0.9),decreasing=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

code something like giving an error;

```
vec <- rbind(diag(3), c(df[1,]))
vectors3d(vec, col=c(rep("black",3), "red"), lwd=2)
```

> Error in ends - starts : non-numeric argument to binary operator

So, the question is how can we supply each rows of `df` to `vectors3d` one by one to create .png picture? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to `unlist` the row i.e. `df[1,]`.  It is still a `data.frame` with 1 row.

```
vec <- rbind(diag(3), unlist(df[1,]))
str(vec)
# num [1:4, 1:3] 1 0 0 -0.123 0 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : chr [1:3] "x" "y" "z"
```

As the OP was using `c` and then `rbind`, it creates a `list` column

```
vec <- rbind(diag(3), c(df[1,]))
str(vec)
#List of 12
# $ : num 1
# $ : num 0
# $ : num 0
# $ : num -0.123
# $ : num 0
# $ : num 1
# $ : num 0
# $ : num -0.0458
# $ : num 0
# $ : num 0
# $ : num 1
# $ : num 0.518
# - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 4 3
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : chr [1:3] "x" "y" "z"
```

After fixing it, the plot should work.

Comment: yes it worked.thanks man. So for second part of the problem how can I do?

Comment: @Alexander I think you can try with `apply` and `MARGIN=1`.  I have to install the package to test it.

Comment: @Alexander Perhaps [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/264563.html) could help you.